# How to create overlapped bar button item programatically

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, xib, uibarbuttonitem, shopping-cart

I know how to create overlap shopping cart and quantity label with xib using uiimage like this
[image]

Now i'm trying to create overlap bar button items programatically but cannot figure out how to position the elements. My attempt:
[image]

My current code for bar button items:

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,
    y: 0.0,
    width: 24.0,
    height: 24.0))
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "my cart", in: nil, compatibleWith: nil), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cartButtonDidTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    let shoppingCartButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    
    shoppingCartQuantityLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    shoppingCartQuantityLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    shoppingCartQuantityLabel.textColor = .white
    shoppingCartQuantityLabel.backgroundColor = .red
    shoppingCartQuantityLabel.textAlignment = .center
    let shoppingCartQuantityLabelItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: shoppingCartQuantityLabel)
    
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [shoppingCartQuantityLabelItem, shoppingCartButton]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea here is to add the label as `subview` inside the `button`. You can adjust the label as per your needs from the below example,

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 24.0, height: 24.0))
button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "my cart"), for: .normal)
let label = UILabel(frame: .init(origin: .init(x: 20, y: -8), size: .init(width: 20, height: 20)))
label.text = "12"
label.textAlignment = .center
label.textColor = .white
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 10)
label.backgroundColor = .red
label.layer.cornerRadius = 10
label.clipsToBounds = true
button.addSubview(label)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code snippet also from Github: https://gist.github.com/freedom27/c709923b163e26405f62b799437243f4#gistcomment-2236010

then set badge to your last right bar button item as below

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [shoppingCartButton]
let lastBarButton = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.last
lastBarButton?.setBadge(text: "10", withOffsetFromTopRight: CGPoint(x: 38, y: -3), andColor: UIColor.red, andFilled: true, andFontSize: 12)
```

[image]